# What is the best HTTP status code to convey "saved, but with errors"?

Tags: http

In my API, I am processing an object which contains a DSL script which can fail syntax/type validation, however I'll still persist the object regardless of any parsing failure, and send back the persisted object along with the failure messages. However, I am having trouble choosing the right HTTP status code to characterize this condition.

From my StackOverflow research:

- `HTTP 400` seems inaccurate since the request was not malformed and could be processed.
- `HTTP 202` seems promising but there isn't really async processing happening.
- `HTTP 422` is popular in other SO posts though I've never seen it used in practice.

Is sending an `HTTP 200` still appropriate in this scenario since nothing really "failed"? Is there a more appropriate HTTP code to use here?

Comment: `422` is used in Laravel by default, and I suspect a variety of other frameworks - there's certainly plenty of usage in the wild. `207 Multi-Status` might be suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any 4xx status should imply that the server did nothing, and the state did no change. Therefore, a 2xx code is the most appropriate.

You could use the Warning header:

- http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7234.html#header.warning

Comment: Seems like a simple enough rule to follow. Thanks!